# How to get prefix codes for charging prepaid sim card

Tags: android, sim-card

I want to make my android app automaticlly detects the prefix codes for charging prepaid sim card,
I don't know if I can do it, but I saw an app that detects it automaticlly.

NOTE:
"prefix codes for charging is used for recharging  prepaid sim cards, every operator has his own codes"

Comment: What is the prefix code?  Is it a number that you dial to top up your SIM?  At a guess, it will be accessible via USSD, and the exact request will be operator dependent. (just a guess)

Comment: i think its not easy i'll try somthing else